# Youtube oembed: How does it calculate the 'width' and 'height' values?

Tags: php, youtube, dimensions, oembed

When I use the oembed URL in my PHP code and extract the `$video->width` and `$video->height` from my uploaded video, I get values back that don't match anything I've seen associated with my Youtube video.

- http://youtu.be/p7ftPYU2_0w
- Original video dimensions, as uploaded to Youtube: **640 x 336**
- oembed returns: **480 x 270**
- Smallest embed option when sharing from Youtube page UI: **560 x 316**

Does anyone know where oembed gets these values? Why does it default to 480? Is there a way to get the true video dimensions, or least bump the default up to 640 x `[proportional_height]`?

My goal is to preserve the native dimensions of the video (no scaling) when embedding on my website, *without* users actually needing to key-in the video dimensions again.

Answer (score 1):

Youtube might generate a content which it could provide for embed content instead of the original video. The width and height of the generated content could be **480 x 270**. So, the oEmbed api could return this value always. AFIK there is no way to get the original dimension of a video value from the api side unless or until the provider provides one.

You could try adjusting the width and size of the video with the help of jquery and css.

[oEmbed](http://oembed.com) spec says `maxwidth` and `maxheight` params could be given while requesting the api. So we could restrict the maximum width and height of the video.

Hope it helps !

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
<iframe title="YouTube video player" width="727" height="430" src='http://www.youtube.com/embed/p7ftPYU2_0w' frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

As far as I know, there is no way of getting the height of the video from embedding. You could use jquery to get the height of the player when the page loads and go from there.

Answer (score 0):

The width and height in an oembed response are the minimum height and width required to properly display the returned html content. This is the video, the interface, any extra title bars or controls or logos, etc etc.

The only time this matters is when an oembed response is requested. The request will specify a width and height that are the maximum supported sizes, the response will specify a minimum size required to display the content.

If the minimum content response size doesn't fit inside the maximum container request size, then the oembed attempt is supposed to fail.

In this case, youtube is stating that 480 x 270 is required to display the youtube interface. It actually says nothing about the video itself, only the interface, since any browser can auto scale any video to any resolution.